# Dynamic SortBy over anonymous type

Tags: c#, .net, linq, dynamic, anonymous-types

How could I perform a `SortBy` operation over a list of an **anonymous type**?

I mean, considering that `enumerable` is an `IEnumerable` of an **anonymous type** that comes as a parameter. For instance:

```
public IQueryable<object> MyMethod(IQueryable<object> enumerable)
{
    return enumerable.SortBy("Name");
}
```

Of course, the anonymous type has a `Name` property

How the `SortBy` inside should be implemented?

Comment: Anonymous types are designed for use within the scope of a single method.    You shouldn't be using anonymous types if you want to be using the type like this from another method.  Create a named type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can perform it by using `System.Linq.Dynamic`;

```
public static class LinqExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> OrderByName<T>(this IQueryable<T> queryable, string sortOrder = null)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder))
        {
            sortOrder = "ASC";
        }
        return queryable.OrderBy(string.Format("Name {0}", sortOrder));
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
   var query = yourContext.Products.OrderByName("DESC");
   var productList = query.ToList();

   public class Product
   {
      public int Id { get;set; }

      public string Name { get; set; }
   }
```

> Note : It would be better if you use `Enum` for `sortOrder` parameter

Comment: OK, thanks for the answer! this should work against IEnumerable<T>, but how about IQueryable<T>? will it perform the sorting using the LINQ-To-Entities provider, for example, using Entity Framework to execute the sorting in the server?